# Stop a docker container from within an alpine image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to stop a docker container from within an alpine image:

```
> docker run -ti alpine sh
/ # poweroff
/ # poweroff -f
poweroff: Operation not permitted
/ # halt
/ # halt -f
halt: Operation not permitted
/ # whoami
root
```

Do you see what is the issue with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot stop a docker image this way.

First, if `poweroff` had to function (and it did in the past, [due to an issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6401)) it would shutdown the entire computer, because of how the `poweroff` binary is working and power halting mechanic is designed on Linux and hardware.

What you have to do in order to properly shutdown your container is to quit the entrypoint (`exit` in shell), or send a signal to this process (eg: `docker stop` sends `SIGTERM` to the running entrypoint before killing it after a period of grace).

If you really want to shutdown the host computer from within a container (why would you ever want to do that?), you can activate the `--privileged` option which will give all power to your root within the container, and then do:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq; echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

Be careful, this will *really* shut down the host, and in a brutal manner. Writing `1` in `sysrq` will activate `sysrq` kernel features, which allows to make keyboard requests to the kernel with the [SysRq key](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/sysrq-key.jpg) but also through the `sysrq-trigger` file. `o` means poweroff.

[Fedora Project - Sysrq](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA/Sysrq)

Comment: Thanks @Fabien. Do you know if it's possible to send this `SIGTERM` from `docker exec`?

Comment: Yes, you can, you just need to know the PID or program name of the entrypoint and then use `kill`

Comment: The OP wasn't asking how to shut down the whole host computer, but to shut down the Docker container itself which is a virtual computer. `Poweroff`, `Halt`, & `Reboot` within a container should work on the container not the host. `Poweroff` should shut down the container, depending on it's restart policy that could restart it or leave it `[Exited]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to terminate the process `sh`, simply with this:

```
exit
```

From within the container. Think a container as an isolated process, not as a virtual machine.